# Make SQL query fail on trying to delete non-existent record

Tags: sql

Is there standard SQL syntax for causing query to fail when a query tries to delete a non-existent entity? E.g.

```
DELETE FROM entity WHERE id = 501;
```

does not fail, even when there is no entity with id = 501. Can it be done in cross-database way?

Comment: What do you mean by fail? You can use conditional statements within your SQL to return a 1 or a 0 (success/failure)?

Comment: A non-existent entity is as good as deleted, So Why should it fail?

Comment: http://xyproblem.info/

Comment: @Satpal I disagree, depending on context it can be reasonable to point out that you try to delete nonexistent entity, just like adding identical one can be no-problem or error depending on context

Comment: Depending on environment you can get deleted row count, where you can tread 0 as error.

Comment: Or you can have a trigger that raises an exception if no rows deleted.

Comment: @jarlh sounds like material for an answer

Comment: Hi @bartop , please can you tag a database you use ?

Comment: And programming API. (JDBC, ODBC, ADO.NET etc.)

Answer (score 1):

Depending on environment you can get deleted row count, where you can tread 0 as error.

Or you can have a trigger that raises an exception if no rows deleted.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way you can handle this in Oracle:

```
BEGIN
  DELETE FROM test
  WHERE       id = 4;
      IF (SQL%NOTFOUND) THEN
         dbms_output.put_line('It is already gone');
     END IF;
END;
/
```

[Here is a small demo.](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=5cd2ccd5e10db24ca78447b8d3649f11)